# Upload database file to google drive AppDataFolder , but Google Drive Manage Apps got a strange app name

Tags: android

I made an android app and tried to upload the database file to google drive AppDataFolder which was successful.

But when I checked the app name in google drive web, setting->Manage Apps , I just found strange app name "quick-district-xxxxxx".

Maybe because i didn't create firebase project and link to GCP project. When I went to firebase console, import CGP project, I found "quick-district-xxxxxx" is the firebase project id.

I Cleaned data of "quick-district-xxxxx" and disconnected from Drive at Google Drive Manage Apps, then ran app upload again, app name on Manage Apps is still "quick-district-xxxxxx"

How do I show app name correctly?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_SIGN_IN) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult,request code="+requestCode);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
            handleSignInResult(data);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Signin request failed");
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}

private void requestSignIn() {
    GoogleSignInClient client=buildGoogleSignInClient();
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(),REQUEST_SIGN_IN);
}

private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder builder= new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN);
    builder.requestEmail();
    builder.requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
    builder.requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions=builder.build();
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.this,signInOptions);
}

private void handleSignInResult(Intent result) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Sign in success");
            GoogleAccountCredential credential=GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE,DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
            credential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());
            Drive.Builder builder=new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential);
            builder.setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name));
            Drive driveService=builder.build();
            Log.d(TAG,"Get google drive service, "+driveService.toString());

            GoogleSignInAccount lastSignedInAccount=GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MainActivity.this);

            if(GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(lastSignedInAccount,new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))) {
                uploadToAppDataFolder(driveService);
            }
            else {
                requestSignIn();
                return;
            }
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Signin error");
        }
    });
}


private String dbName="database.db";

private void uploadToAppDataFolder(final Drive driveService) {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setName(dbName);
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
            java.io.File databasePath=getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(dbName);
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/x-sqlite3", databasePath);
            try {
                File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                        .setFields("id")
                        .execute();
                Log.d(TAG,"uploadToAppDataFolder,filedId="+file.getId()+",parents="+file.getParents()+",spaces="+file.getSpaces());
                listFilesInAppDataFolder(driveService);
            }
            catch(UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"uploadToAppDataFolder, "+e.toString());
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),REQUEST_SIGN_IN);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"uploadToAppDataFolder,"+e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```